# Why are transactions missing data?

Tags: square-connect

I am retrieving transactions via the Connect API v2, however, none of the returned records include order_id, customer_id, or cardholder_name.

All of this data is linked and viewable within the dashboard.

Am I missing something?

Comment: If you are seeing something that doesn't line up with my answer, could you post your application_id and an example transaction we could look up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`order_id` - This field would only be filled if you used the [`CreateOrder`](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-createorder) endpoint and passed that order to the `Charge` endpoint for an itemized e-commerce transaction. It would not be there if you created an order in the Point of Sale.

`customer_id` - This is only filled in if the merchant (or app/site) explicitly attached a customer to the transaction. Some transactions get associated to automatically created customers that you don't have the data for, if you don't explicitly create the customer.

`cardholder_name` - You would only see this if the customer paid with Card on File. If you look at the [data model in the documentation](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#type-card) `The cardholder name. This value is present only if this object represents a customer's card on file.`

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response.  I am working with Point of Sale transactions, just looking to report the data via the API.
It looks like this is not possible?

Comment: If you want to get the itemizations from Point of Sale transactions, you can look at the tenders in the v1 payments API. Customer information is also available, you just have to explicitly add customer in the point of sale during transactions.

Comment: Fantastic, I've found what I'm after.  Thanks!

Comment: Just to confirm, there's no way to use the V2 api to get the itemizations from POS transactions? I was trying to avoid keeping a mapping between V1 catalog ids and V2 catalog ids and just purely use the V2 API, so just wanted to double check. Much appreciated.

Comment: Correct, you will need the v1 APIs for POS itemizations